# Como fazer Stripe apenas com CSS?

Tags: css

Como eu posso fazer um **stripe** (aquele listradinho na diagonal) apenas com CSS?

A imagem abaixo ilustra melhor a minha dúvida.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o [`repeating-linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient) para isso.

Um exemplo prático, tirado da própria documentação, seria isto:

```css
div {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  border-color: #000000;
  padding: 10px;
}
#grad1 {
  background-image: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(26, 198, 204), rgb(26, 198, 204) 7%, rgb(100, 100, 100) 10%);
  background-image: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(26, 198, 204), rgb(26, 198, 204) 7%, rgb(100, 100, 100) 10%);
  background-image: -o-repeating-linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(26, 198, 204), rgb(26, 198, 204) 7%, rgb(100, 100, 100) 10%);
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(26, 198, 204), rgb(26, 198, 204) 7%, rgb(100, 100, 100) 10%);
}
#grad2 {
  background-color: black;
  background-image: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent, transparent 25px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 25px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50px);
  background-image: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent, transparent 25px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 25px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50px);
  background-image: -o-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent, transparent 25px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 25px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50px);
  background-image: -ms-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent, transparent 25px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 25px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50px);
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent, transparent 25px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 25px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50px);
}
```

```html
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient -->

<ol>
  <li>repeating gradient
    <div id="grad1"></div>
  </li>
  <li>Zebra pattern
    <div id="grad2"></div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Não se esqueça de [ver a tabela de compatibilidade.](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient#Browser_Compatibility)